# Reference Request: Limits of the sequence $M^k\vec{v}$, where $M$ a real symmetric matrix and $v$ is a fixed vector

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

**Context** Let $M$ be a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix.
By the spectral theorem for Hermitian matrices, we can find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ of orthogonal eigenvectors $\vec{\varepsilon}_1, \dots, \vec{\varepsilon}_n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$. In this eigenbasis, the linear transformation $M$ is represented by the diagonal matrix $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$.

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed vector. Using our eigenbasis, we can write $\vec{v} = \sum a_i\vec{\varepsilon}_i$ for a unique choice of real coefficients $a_i$.

This is where our (simple) result begins. It's very easy to calculate $M^k\vec{v}$ in the eigenbasis, since

$$M^k\vec{v} = M^k\left( \sum a_i\cdot\vec{\varepsilon}_i \right) = \sum a_i \cdot M^k\vec{\varepsilon}_i = \sum a_i \cdot \lambda_i ^k \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}_i$$

As $k$ gets large, the sum above becomes dominated by the non-zero terms $a_i \cdot \lambda_i ^k \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}_i$ for which $|\lambda_i|$ is largest (The "largest principal axes" of sorts). There's a small complicating factor: some eigenvalues can be negative, so the sequence $S_{even} = \{M^{2k}\vec{v}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges, *up to scaling by some positive number*, to one vector, and the sequence $S_{odd} = \{M^{2k+1}\vec{v}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges, up to scaling by a positive number, to another vector.

---

**Question:** Provided I haven't made any silly mistakes and stated something false, I'd like a (citeable) reference for the result about the sequences converging.
I.e., a reference for the fact that if $M$ is a real symmetric matrix, and $v$ is a fixed vector, then both the following sequences $S_{odd}$ and $S_{even}$ converge, where:

$$S_{even} = \left\{ \frac{M^{2k}\vec{v}}{||M^{2k}\vec{v}||} \right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$$

and

$$S_{odd} = \left\{ \frac{M^{2k+1}\vec{v}}{||M^{2k}\vec{v}||} \right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$$

Comment: Do you truly need a reference. Because I find that the proof is not very hard to write.

Comment: You need only to prove that $S_{even}$ converges since $S_{odd} = MS_{even}$

Comment: @Youem If a reference exists, I'd rather use it :P It's extra space in a paper that is already likely to have, by necessity, a lot of "fluff".

Comment: It is may be hard to find a reference with the exact proof. But the proof can be written on three lines at most.

Comment: @Youem Fair enough, reference hunting may very well be more trouble than it's worth.